# Exception in thread "JobGenerator" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/scheduler/InputInfo

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to run a Spark-Kafka integration for word count job (in Java) on a local machine. My code is as shown below:

```
JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages =  KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc, String.class, String.class,
            StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topicsSet);

JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(new MyFunction());
JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(str ->  Arrays.asList(str.split(" ")));
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> ones = words.mapToPair(new MyPairFunction());
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> counts = ones.reduceByKey((a, b) -> a + b);
```

But when I run it with **spark-submit** command I get the following long list of exceptions:

```
22:33:04,286 WARN  org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem                         - Using default name DAGScheduler for source because spark.app.id is not set.
Exception in thread "JobGenerator" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/scheduler/InputInfo at   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.DirectKafkaInputDStream.compute(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:124) at   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
at   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun $1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:342)
at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:339)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:342)
at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:339)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FlatMappedDStream.compute(FlatMappedDStream.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:342)
at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:339)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:342)
at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:339)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ShuffledDStream.compute(ShuffledDStream.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:342)
at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:339)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:120)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$2.apply(JobGenerator.scala:247)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$2.apply(JobGenerator.scala:245)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:245)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:181)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.InputInfo
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 73 more
```

I am using this maven assembly plugin shown below to create a jar file with all dependencies:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong or missing.